# How can I revoke tokens created through Cognito oauth/token url

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth, amazon-cognito, serverless, api-gateway

We have an application implemented on api-gateway and lambda,
the authentication is carried by tokens generated on Cognito,
Cognito has the Client credentials OAuth Flow with custom scopes.
We are using the oauth/token url to generate access tokens, we tried to create refresh tokens, but the oauth/authorize isn't working, because the Client credential flow restrict the Authorization code grant.

On the middle of the process we need these tokens to be revoked,
but the oauth/revoke needs the refresh token that we can't generate
because of the chosen flow,
How can we can revoke those tokens?

Comment: This should help: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-revocation.html

Comment: Thanks but we can't create refresh tokens because of the oauth flow we are using, so we are using access tokens instead.

Comment: When you’re using OAUTH2.0 flows, Cognito still returns the refresh tokens. See step 5 here https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/understanding-amazon-cognito-user-pool-oauth-2-0-grants/